# How to format date in React material-ui date-picker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, react-redux, momentjs

I'm implementing redux-form with a material-ui date-picker field. Date is perfectly set in field but when I try to send it to the back-end API format of the date is:

`BeginDate_1: Tue Nov 14 2017 15:03:43 GMT+0530 (IST)`

I'm trying to change this format to 'YYYY-mm-dd' format before sending it to the the back-end API.

I tried `momentjs` for formatting, but I couldn't get the result I wanted.

Here's what I've tried:

**Home.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as moment  from 'moment';

class Home extends Component {

renderCalendarField= ({
                          input,
                          label,
                          meta: {touched, error},
                          children,
                          ...custom
                      }) => (
    <DatePicker
        floatingLabelText={label}
        errorText={touched && error}
        {...input}
        value = {input.value !== ''? new Date(input.value) : null}
        onChange={(event, value) => input.onChange(value)}
        children={children}
        {...custom}
        formatDate={(date) => moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}

    />

)

render() {

    const startDate = new Date();

    const {handleSubmit} = this.props;

    return (

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>


            <div>
                <Field name="BeginDate_1" component={this.renderCalendarField} label="DEPARTURE" minDate={startDate} />
            </div>


            <div>
                <button type="submit">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>

        </form>

    );

}

}

const LogInForm = reduxForm({
form: 'MaterialUiForm', // a unique identifier for this form
validate
})(Home);

export default connect(mapStateTOProps, {getCity})(LogInForm);
```

The console output is still:

`BeginDate_1:Tue Nov 14 2017 15:03:43 GMT+0530 (IST)`

How can I format this date in `YYYY-mm-dd` format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`formatDate` prop on the `DatePicker` is used to `format` the `Display Date` and not the actual value. What you need to do is, format the the value in the `onSubmit` function using `moment`

```
onSubmit (values) {

   const beginDate = moment(values.BeginDate_1).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
   console.log(beginDate);
   //other things
}
```

According to the **[material-ui/DatePicker docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker)**:

> **formatDate**: function
>
> This function is called to format the date displayed in the input
>   field, and should return a string. By default if no locale and
>   DateTimeFormat is provided date objects are formatted to `ISO 8601 YYYY-MM-DD.`
>
> Signature:
>
> ```
> function(date: object) => any
> date: Date object to be formatted.
> returns (any): The formatted date.
> ```

Comment: getting this error : TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_12_moment__(...).formate is not a function

Comment: That was a typo in my answer. It should be `format` and not `formate`