# Changing material-ui’s pickers format

Tags: reactjs, css, material-ui

How can i change the picker format with the new version of material ui (1.2.1) to dd/mm/yyyy instead of mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format date in React material-ui date-picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47282701/how-to-format-date-in-react-material-ui-date-picker)

Comment: There used to be a date picker. But not anymore

Comment: could you please explain this more. are you using material-ui-pickers(https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/material-ui-pickers) or pickers from material-ui(https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/) itself

Comment: I use pickers from material-ui. Not material-ui-pickers